# How do i find out the size of my motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

I have a P8H67-M EVO Rev 3, and I'm not sure what size it is. I have checked the website http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H67M_EVO/ and the box and i have also looked around the web, but i can't find the size anywhere. If someone could tell me where i could find the size of it, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Any online shop will provide the physical characteristics of it.  This question shows absolutely no research effort.  If you had checked the ASUS website and/or any online retailer website you would have discovered the answer to this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is shows no effort except posting here.

Comment: I am calling you on that statement because every retailer I went to bad the uATX description and the physical size

Comment: http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H67M/specifications/ Answer is there under Form Factor.

Comment: Asking for others to scroll down a webpage is out of scope

Answer (score 2):

From the [specifications on the Asus site](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H67M_EVO/specifications/) (scroll to the bottom):

> uATX Form Factor 
>   9.6 inch x 9.6 inch ( 24.4 cm x 24.4 cm )

More information regarding the microATX (µATX) form factor is available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroATX).